# JasperReports: report parameter as an argument for message bundle lookup

Tags: jasper-reports

How to look up a particular internationalized property based on a report parameter?

This works, but is static:

```
$R{some_literal_string}
```

This works too, but is not internationalized:

```
$P{key_to_parameters_map_element}
```

What I need is:

```
$R{$P{key_to_parameters_map_element}}
```

Unfortunately, I get a pile of error messages:

```
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
                value = str("$P{key_to_parameters_map_element")}; //$JR_EXPR_ID=13$
```

This doesn't change anything:

```
$R{$P{key_to_parameters_map_element}.toString()}
```

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
str($P{key_to_parameters_map_element})
```

Quite intuitive, isn't it?